# Generating relative Prime number of a user defined prime number?

Tags: c++, c

I'm creating a program in C and I need to use relative prime numbers in sequence using an algorithm so that the user can select the first number in the sequence.

So far I have managed to create a function that creates relative prime numbers based on one or more inputted by a user but not one that finds the next smallest relative prime.

Either that or a way to produce the smallest relative prime number to a user defined number would be ideal.

Any ideas?

Also, I cannot get `gcd` to work so I created my own. Do i have to include a specific library other than `math.h` and `stdio.h`?

Comment: (`the user can select the first number in the sequence` what if she doesn't? Or does?) `one or more input [numbers]` one relative prime per input number or one relative prime to all of the input numbers?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the next smallest relative prime, then I think you need to loop from the user's inputted number (e.g. if users input 3, then you need to loop from 4), and then check whether that number is relatively prime.

To check whether two numbers are relatively prime, you can use gcd, and one very famous algorithm to do this is to use Euclid's algorithm. You don't need to include a specific library, it's basically just looping and doing modulo. Take a look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).